# Taking query from the user input

Tags: prolog

How can I ask the user to put his query after executing some lines of codes?Eg-

```
woman(X):-
  ( X=18->write('yes'),nl
    ;
  ).
man(Y):-
  ( X=18->write('yes'),nl
    ;
  ).
main:-
 woman(18),
  write('Enter your query'),nl,
  "**HERE I WANT USER TO CALL ANY QUERY EITHER woman(X) or man(X) ??Can I Do it????**
```

I want to first execute `main` and then the user has to enter his query.Is this possible??I know he can directly call the query but can he do it after executing `main`?

Comment: If you want to prompt the user for the query, are you then wanting to limit their syntax to, for example, `woman(X)`? If you just want to do that literally, then you can use `call/1`.

Comment: @lurker No actually I have large number of predicate and user can call anyone.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of program output and a couple of sample user inputs/responses?